# how to get form validation from angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, components

I know how to set form validation from angular 1.5

for example:
`$scope.voiceForm.$setValidity`

but how can i `get` the `form-validaiton` status from the component code?

couldn't find in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,

Use this reference: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/n7uzrets/)

```
    <form name="demoForm">
      <input name="amount" type="number" ng-model="amount" max="100">
      <div ng-messages="demoForm.amount.$error">
        <div ng-message="number">Should be a number</div>
        <div ng-message="max">The number is too large.</div>
      </div>
    </form>
    {{demoForm.amount.$valid}}
```

If you take the code and tests by adding it outside the **"form"**
{{demoForm.amount.$valid}} will give you the status of the form at all times.

By default a correct number will be set to "true" but if you put a number such as 12020929292 that is too long, it will skip the error and {{demoForm.amount.$valid}} will go from true to false immediately.